# An exception occurred while creating local git repository -Openshift

Tags: git, openshift

we are developing the project and upload and run it  in Openshift  from past 4 months.
our project in JAVA platform and using phpmyadmin database of openshift and using eclipse kepler IDE and we configure openshift in eclipse and its working well..but yesterday some conflicts occur while pushing and pulling file so we decide to delete the application from eclipse ide and import it again from openshift,while doing, the following error occur in system.

> An exception occurred while creating local git repository. Clone
>   operation failed, with failed cleanup: Could not delete file
>   G:\wallpaper\mindapp.git\objects\pack\pack-3de59be603008fc89ec4ca25ce9bd96ce6751f99.pack.
>   Manual cleanup may be required.

we change git location,workspace location even try in different laptops but still remain the same error

we tried OS - Windows 8, Windows 7

Comment: According to [egit sources](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/egit/egit/+/1429d0bf8ae7f414c9d3022f7cc7818bf1cb8ac0/org.eclipse.egit.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/core/op/CloneOperation.java) (line 170) this error is shown when `clone `operation fails and then cleanup fails. The question is why `clone` fails... Did you try to clone your repository using standard git utility?

Comment: ya.its working well before but now same above error occured in .pack file ,so i cannot import my openshift project into eclipse.i change many locations for git and no response still same error killing me

Comment: I can't realize a problem based on given info. Not enough information. Maybe you can provide more, can you?

Comment: i trying to clone my repository.. while cloning its shows the error.. it only occurs in windows.. ther is no ssh key problem.. i think prob in file size...

Comment: Really? :) It is obvious. You said about some conflicts while pushing: what's the conflicts? Are your repo public?

Comment: no its not public. i have deleted that project in local repository. so no conflicts. that's why i want to clone. i think prob in pack.windowMemory..

Comment: Have you access to remote repository via ssh or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57547/discussion-between-romangotsiy-and-hala-rowan).

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just delete the select file from explorer?

so for example go to the local directory and go to .git\objects\pack\ inside that directory, then delete the selected pack file (or is it a server side issue?)